Where to install UV light in attic ductwork
Question is do they install it in line after the air handler? in which case it looks difficult to replace. Or is it installed before, near the intake 4 inch filter, in which case it looks easier to replace.
How long do these lights last?
How would you know if the lamp has died and needs replacement ?

You just have a 4" intake filter?

@JACK  there is a 1 inch on the main floor. Then a large duct going to attic where there is an additional 4 inch filter; then a 2 foot by 2 foot area which is before the air handler unit starts.

What make and model is your UV lamp? A link to a webpage would be very helpful. There are many different types of UV lamps. Preferably yours is UV-C which only emits the 254 nm wavelength. 180 nm is the ozone-producing wavelength

@MikeWaters  have not purchased it yet.

Preferably, AFTER the air handler.
I used to be in the air purifier business, and sold and installed germicidal lamps for HVAC systems. These lamps did not emit ozone, only purifying hydroxl ions. If yours does emit ozone, it is especially important to mount them after your air handler.
Ideally, germicidal lamps should be be mounted near the discharge (cold air) side of the evaporator coil to kill mold and eliminate the slime which often is present in more humid areas.
I did an experiment once and mounted one on the supply side of the coil in my own house. Sure enough, that fresh smell of hydroxyl ions was blocked by the coil.
Here is a link to the relevant section of our old website. It has much information about the proper selection and installation of UV-C lamps.

We no longer sell these, and I don't know where to buy them anymore.

If you don't have a real odor problem, then you don't need ozone. Germicidal lamps will eliminate some odors.

How do you know if the lamp died? do you have to check it like an air filter?!

I don't know, but I would presume you could measure it's current draw. I'm a bit skeptical about whether air/dust passing by will actually be exposed long enough to make a real difference though I am sure someone other than manufacturers has studied the matter

A UV-C lamp usually has a lifetime stated by the manufacturer. Some last only one year. Others last quite a bit longer. The hot-cathode Philips lamps we still use last quite a few years, but the clear synthetic quartz envelope degrades ("solarizes") a little more each year.

The Philips lamps had a very thin coating of titanium dioxide on the inside. Without that, the UV-C rays degrade the synthetic quartz (it's not glass) so they pass less and less UV as time goes on.

If the clear envelope has a yellow tint when held up to a sheet of paper, that's a sign of solarization. But the only way to be sure is with a suitable radiometer.
